# I thought my vbscript button would execute but I may be missing something

Tags: html, vbscript

I made a vbscript that runs and works perfectly, thought I could just plug it into the html with script tags and it would execute the same. NOT TRUE, please tell me what I need to do to get the button to work. As a script it would log in automatically and navigate to a page, I want that to happen when a button is pressed on my webpage.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add a Lead</title>
    <script type="text/vbscript">
    function Execute()
    {
    Dim IE
    Dim WRI
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = 1 
    IE.navigate "http://rentalapp.zillow.com/"
    Do While (IE.Busy)
    WScript.Sleep 10
     Loop
     Set WRI = IE.document.getElementByID("username")
     WRI.Value = "username"
     Set WRI = IE.document.getElementByID("password")
     WRI.Value = "password"
     Set WRI = IE.document.Forms(0)
     WRI.Submit
    WScript.Sleep 801
    IE.navigate "http://rentalapp.zillow.com/leads/add/"
    document.getElementById("field2").value=document.getElementById("field1").value; }    </script>    </head>

    <body>
    <button onclick="Execute()">Add A Lead</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

please help

Comment: Curly brackets and semicolons are not valid syntax elements in VBScript. Also, "doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. How *exactly* does it "not work"? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a vbscript programmer, but I think the issue is with your function declaration. This is how W3C declares a vbscript function for a simple alert [example](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_msgbox.asp):

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
    sub Execute()
        MsgBox("Hello world")
    end sub
</script>
<body>
    <button onClick="Execute()">Add A Lead</button>
</body>
```

Comment: OK so that works but it still won't enter the login information. Again I remind you that it works as a vbscript but in html it dies but at least you got me to the next step and for that I thank you. Before I couldn't even get the button to react but now it pulls up another window with the url address I assigned.

Comment: Yes sorry I cannot dive into code. But it sounds like a compatibility issue here. Are you aware of the differences between Visual Basic for Applications, VBScript, and Visual Basic?